# Generating random numbers from best probability distributions?

Tags: python, statistics, data, distribution, descriptive-statistics

I have done some statistical distributions on real-world [data](https://filebin.net/at1xgqdqw2nk5dsh). The distribution fitting gives me the below results (lognormal fits the best on data based on chi-squared test):

```
Best Distribution fits with parameters:
---------------------------------------

Distribution: lognorm
Parameters: (0.5921510072108613, -0.006454418407435666, 0.021090953536473916)

Distribution: expon
Parameters: (2e-06, 0.018877666177431276)

Distribution: pareto
Parameters: (11.057961210885452, -0.20440106940633995, 0.20436985884797232)
```

Here, i want to achieve two things:

- Using the best parameters,how to generate the new synthetic data that represent our original data?.
  Does the [rvs method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html) in python is useful?
- Compare the actual and generated data distribution fitting as shown in below figure.

[image]

Comment: Yes. The rvs method will be useful. If you have decided to use lognormal distribution, you can check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm for specific examples of generating random numbers.

Comment: You can use [Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) metric to compare distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Lots of options.

Most would recommend you use CDFs instead of histograms. So convert your observed distribution to empirical CDF (in R it’s ecdf() - I dint know python). Then, plot another line that is the theoretical CDF using your best-fit parameters over the span of a to b, where a to b gives you at least the same coverage as your original data set limits.

Alternatively you could go for a chi-square option that’ll give you observed vs predicted and can be plotted as histogram but I don’t find that better in most cases, though it might make quantitative comparison more accessible

Comment: Just to add a bit on @HEITS: To plot CDF for Python, you can go through this [link](http://stanford.edu/~raejoon/blog/2017/05/16/python-recipes-for-cdfs.html).